# How do I run the build script in this docker container

Tags: docker, predictionio

I am trying to run this container here: https://github.com/mingfang/docker-predictionio. I built the docker image, but I don't know how to run the 'build' script in the repo. I tried `./build` but that gives me this error:

```
invalid argument "." for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error? I tried passing an argument as a name for the docker image like `./build dockerimage` as there is an IMAGE variable in the script. But that also throws the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `$IMAGE` variable is set by script `helper`. This script expects that the repo is in a directory named `docker-expecter-image-name`, so if you used default checkout options your repo would be in directory `docker-predictionio` and your $IMAGE would be `predictionio`. My guess is that you checked out the repo under some other directory name, so the variable `$IMAGE` is not set correctly.

Note: Script `run` expects the image to be named `predictionio`, so if the repo directory is named for example `docker-mypredictionio` then the `build` script would execute correctly and the `run` script would not.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it that worked! That is exactly what happened.
Unfortunately though it seems PIO is not working as it should. I ran `pio status` and I am getting an error that it cannot establish connection:
`Connection refused (java.net.ConnectException)`.
Do you happen to know why this is? I can't seem to find much information doing some googling.

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so are you using Docker For Windows of Docker Toolbox?

Comment: No I am using Mac

Comment: Same question: Docker for Mac or Docker Toolbox?

Comment: Docker for Mac. Not Toolbox

Comment: I got the same error, because it couldn't connect to elasticsearch. I don't know how to fix this, but since it is outside the scope of your original question, I'd suggest closing this question by accepting my answer and either opening another one with detailed description of your problem or contacting the maintainer of this Docker image

Answer (score 0):

This image are not work because use elasticsearch 5.x, the ES 5.x not allow run as root. Try another image.